# задача не проходит по времени

Tags: c++

> В соревнованиях по хоккею участвует N команд. Сколько существует
> вариантов распределения комплектов золотых, серебряных и бронзовых
> медалей, если одно призовое место может занять только одна команда?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

long long facktN(int n) {
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    return n * facktN(n - 1);
}

int main() {
    int n, k = 3, ans = 0;
    cin >> n;
    int r = n - k;
    cout << facktN(n) / facktN(r);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Какая задача?..

Comment: В соревнованиях по хоккею участвует N команд. Сколько существует вариантов распределения комплектов золотых, серебряных и бронзовых медалей, если одно призовое место может занять только одна команда?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cout << (n * (n-1) * (n-2));
```

> В соревнованиях по хоккею участвует N команд. Сколько существует
> вариантов распределения комплектов золотых, серебряных и бронзовых
> медалей, если одно призовое место может занять только одна команда?

```
if (n > 2) cout << (n * (n-1) * (n-2));
else if (n == 2) cout << 2; // только золото и серебро
else cout << 1; // Сыграть не получится, но золото, небось дадут?
```

Comment: Я пытался и так, но все ровно пишет не правильный ответ

Comment: Это ровно то, что написано у вас в вопросе, только оно «проходит по времени»

Comment: а как сделать так, чтобы и ответ прошел, не подскажите?

Comment: Проверил на acmp, работает)

Comment: Странно, у меня только 20 тестов проходит, 21 - нет

Comment: А все, спасибо. Надо было выбрать тип переменной long long